# Issue while package reset on xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, package

Showing Recent Errors Only
git@github.com:XXX/iOS_Freestyle_Crew_SDK.git: The remote repository could not be accessed. Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and that the correct credentials have been supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved after providing permissions to the git account for that particular folder or group.